# Is there a depletion mode MOSFET library for LTspice?

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, simulation

I haven't found any depletion mode MOSFET model library for LTspice. Does one exist?

Comment: Use an enhancement mode device but add an offset to the gate source voltage.

Comment: That's because they don't exist (or at least are extremely rare). Siliconix (no Microchip) has some.

Comment: Use Andy's idea, or another alternative is you can find an actual depletion device part number and download the manufacturer's model and import it.  Lastly, you can also copy an nmos `.model` line from `Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\cmp\standard.mos`, paste it into your schematic as a "SPICE directive", and then add a minus sign to the VTO number.

Comment: @SteKulov Would you mind elaborating on these methods in an answer? How does adding "an offset to the gate-source voltage" work? And adding the `.model` directive does not seem to override the device model.

Comment: @handle  Wow, almost 3 years.  I'm too lazy to write up an answer, but here are some screenshots.  [First is Andy's idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s8kn.png), where you add a voltage source offset equal to `2*Vto` before the gate.  [Then is my idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9OQR.png) of modifying the `Vto` parameter of the model statement.  The model directive indeed overrides the built-in model, but if you're having problems with that you can just name it something different.  Both methods produce identical results.

Comment: @SteKulov Thank you, that's what I tried, without success, so my issues must have another cause. I'll try to narrow it down!

Answer (score 5):

See my webpage: http://bordodynov.ltwiki.org/
file VDMOS for LTspiceXVII, file is standard.mos.XVII.txt
There are several transistors in this file. You only need to select those n-channel transistors, which have a negative threshold voltage.

Answer (score 0):

From [Ste Kulov's comment(s)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/554427/is-there-a-depletion-mode-mosfet-library-for-ltspice#comment1859116_554427):

First is [Andy's idea](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/554427/is-there-a-depletion-mode-mosfet-library-for-ltspice/700062#comment1445739_554427), where you add a voltage source offset equal to 2*Vto before the gate:

[image]

Then is my idea of modifying the Vto parameter of the model statement:

... you can also copy an nmos .model line from Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\cmp\standard.mos, paste it into your schematic as a "SPICE directive", and then add a minus sign to the VTO number.

[image]

The model directive indeed overrides the built-in model, but if you're having problems with that you can just name it something different. Both methods produce identical results.

... another alternative is you can find an actual depletion device part number and download the manufacturer's model and import it.